# Rails.env.production? returns true in staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, production-environment

I've got two rails apps deployed on heroku. One in staging - the other in production environment. I have also set up a staging.rb file in my config directory. For deploying to my staging app, I use "git push staging master" but the condition Rails.env.production? still returns true, which I only want in my prod app. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to set environment to `staging` in heroku. So, you have to use this command

```
heroku config:set RAILS_ENV=staging
```

Comment: Thank you that's very helpful. Here, is a good resource to learn about Rails environment: https://medium.com/@farsi_mehdi/how-environment-check-works-in-ruby-on-rails-4cfbd0434605